# Not showing exact values in addition in AX

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

```
static void vall(Args _args)
{
real value1        =  90077404192159.75;
real value2        =  90077254918474.73;

real valueSum;

 ;

 valueSum = value1 + value2;

    error(strFmt("%1", valueSum));    // returns 180,154,659,110,634.50
// result should be 180,154,659,110,634.48;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of reals is -(10)127 to (10)127 with a precision of 16 significant digits.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa878630.aspx